# What is the correct formalization of the statement: "Zero is the only neutral element in respect to addition"

Tags: propositional-calculus, predicate-logic

In my home work assignment I was asked to formalize different statements. One of them was (assuming that we are talking about whole numbers): "Zero is the only neutral element in respect to addition."
My way of formalizing it was:
$$\forall_x \left( x + 0 = x \; \wedge \; \forall_y \left( (y + x = x) \rightarrow y = 0 \right) \right) $$
I thought that to formalize it correctly I need to state, first of all, that zero is neutral element with respect to addition, and after that to state that zero is the only neutral element, by saying that for any other element, if it's neutral with respect to addition, that means that it is zero.

Today I get back my assignment and my TA marked this formalization as not correct, stated that my formalization is "stronger" that required, and provided the following formalization as the correct one:
$$\forall_y \forall_x \left( (x + y = x) \rightarrow (y = 0) \right)$$

In my understanding this formalization means that for all $y$ if $y$ is neutral element with respect to addition then $y$ is zero, but in this formalization there is no statement about existence of zero as neutral element.

So my question is: What is the right formalization of the statement and if my way of formalization was wrong, please explain why it's not correct.

Comment: Your TA is correct if they would consider the statement "$12$ is the only perfect square prime number" true. -- They may have a point (but remember that points are small by definition) though because in "$x$ is neutral if and **only** if $x=0$", we consider the "if" and the "only if" to stand for the two directions of implication. Then again, this is "only if", not "only".  -- The main problem is of course that *natural language* is not formal so that the discussion of the meaning (or possibly meanings) is first a task for linguists ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on the logical interpretation of the English phrase "Zero is the only neutral element", and specifically the word "only". Does it mean *precisely one*, or does it mean *at most one*? Your interpretation gives the former, his interpretation gives the latter. Personally I prefer your interpretation, but this appears to be what the difference comes down to.

As a side note, I would add that I would consider both of your formalizations wrong. Consider for example the model $(\mathbb Z \cup \{\infty\}, +, 0)$, where $+$ is defined the obvious way on $\infty$: anything plus infinity equals infinity. In this case, I would still call 0 the only neutral element for addition: it is the only element that, when added to anything, gives back that same element. However, neither your nor your TA's sentence holds in this structure: instantiating either sentence with $x = y = \infty$ shows that the sentences do not hold. I would consider a *correct* formalization to be
$$
\forall x (x + 0 = x) \land \forall y(\forall x (x + y = x) \to y = 0).
$$
(Although even this may not be the right formalization if $+$ is not commutative....)

Comment: Sorry - I just noted what you meant. At qa quick glance I had thought tat the only difference between the two statements was the part that $0$ is neutral

Comment: I don't see what interpretation of "neutral element" gives you $\infty$ as a neutral element. On the contrary. It is a counter-neutral element. $x+y=x$ for *all* $y$, rather than $x+y=x$ for all $x$, in the case where $y$ is $0$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, yes, that is my point. OP's two sentences both fail in $(\mathbb Z \cup \{\infty\}, +, 0)$ despite the fact that I would say "0 is the only neutral element" is true in this structure.

Comment: I also don't understand your "correct" formulation. Since $\forall$ distributes over $\land$, this is the same as $\forall x\forall y\forall x(x+0=x\land(x+y=x\rightarrow y=0))$. So you just quantify over $x$ twice. Yes, it is "strict" to the natural language formalization which is "completely unambiguous", but it is not significantly different from the OPs.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, $\forall$ does not distribute over $\to$, though, which is the important difference.

Comment: Also, I don't understand the insistence of moving away from $\Bbb Z$ with addition, or mentioning that $+$ might not be commutative. Understanding implicit context is important in mathematics. If you expect the readers of your answer to understand that $\Bbb Z$ denotes the integers, with $+$ as the addition, why even mention $+$ might be "not commutative"? What if I chose $\Bbb Z$ to denote some other set, perhaps the real numbers? That would be confusing, right? The OP asks in the context of the integers, and insistence of different contexts is just... confusing here.

Comment: Where, and who, made any claims that $\forall$ distributes over $\to$?

Comment: Your sentence in the second comment on this answer is not equivalent to the sentence in my post, because my final $\forall x$ sits inside an implication that you cannot "distribute it out of".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85656/discussion-between-mees-de-vries-and-asaf-karagila).

Comment: Let us not continue this discussion in chat.

Comment: Fine, then let me repeat the final comment I just typed into the chat box (in case anyone else reads this): Regarding different contexts: if you ask to formulate something like "0 is the unique neutral element of $\mathbb Z$", you are implicitly asking about possible different domains. Because any sentence that expresses that 0 is the unique neutral element of $\mathbb Z$ is equivalent to $\top$. Thus you need to express the wider idea of a neutral element in the specific case for $\mathbb Z$, no matter what.

Comment: Actually now I can see what do you mean by "both of our formalization are wrong". Because in all courses that I took we never consider $\infty$ as an element, I could never thought about your example. But seeing this example I can see where my formalization fall  wrong (considering the model you provided).

Comment: Obviously I was talking about $ ( \mathbb{Z}, +) $

Comment: Mees, no, you're over-reading my point. When I say "write a sentence that states that $0$ is the only neutral element", what I am really asking is to write a sentence that defines $0$ in the structure $(\Bbb Z,+)$ through that property. Again, implicit understanding plays a significant role in learning. Over-insistence on formalization obscures understanding; and over-pedantry inhibit growths.

Comment: @asafkaragila OK. That is not my understanding of that English sentence/the assignment. Perhaps you should write an answer with that interpretation.

Answer (score 2):

First, as others have pointed out, the use of 'only' in English is ambiguous.

Still, given that it says 'the only', I would very much give preference to your interpretation instead of your TA's interpretation.

Second, here is a more efficient way to formalize your interpretation:

$$\forall x \forall y (x + y = x \leftrightarrow y = 0)$$

Finally, while this formalization will work just fine in practice when working with numbers, I have to agree with Mees that a technically more correct symbolization would be of the form:

$$\forall y (y \text{ is a neutral element for addition } \leftrightarrow y = 0)$$

i.e.:

$$\forall y (\forall x \ x + y = x \leftrightarrow y = 0)$$

Or, if one wants to get really pedantic:

$$\forall y (\forall x ( x + y = x \land y + x = x) \leftrightarrow y = 0)$$